# Dynamic increment bootstrap progress-bar in a php foreach loop?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, progress-bar

I generate about 150 invoices in a php foreach loop (with dompdf class). This takes about 40s for the page/rendering to finish so I'm wondering if I can I place a bootstrap progress-bar before the foreach loop starts and inside this php foreach loop the width of this progress-bar should be incremented.

Is this possible? With jquery?

```
<div id="foo" class="progress progress-striped active">
  <div class="progress-bar" style="width: 1%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Though the above answer is intriguing.What concerns me is this : http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/126671/is-it-considered-bad-practice-to-have-php-in-your-javascript . Read the second answer on using javascript on php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://w3shaman.com/article/php-progress-bar-script) you have a good example about how to implement progress bar by PHP.

**Here is the technique**.

> Create at least one div element with a certain width in your HTML
>   document for displaying the progress bar.
>
> Estimate the progress percentage in your PHP script. This number will
>   be used to determine the progress bar's length.
>
> "Echo" the Javascript for updating the content of div element above
>   with a div that the width percentage is same as the calculated
>   progress. Also give the div a different background color or background
>   image so we can see it.
>
> "Flush" it to the browser.

Comment: This works in a "naked" test site. But on the invoice generating php file the progressbar stays on 1% the whole time and when the invoice rendering (php foreach loop) is done the progress-bar switches to 100% immediately

Comment: **update** I think it works now! I had $(function() { jscode } this didn't work. But when I only write the jscode in the foreach loop (without that $(function() beginning) it works!